# Filtrar meses, años y días en Query Builder Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, querybuilder

Estoy trabajando en symfony y tengo que hacer una consulta con query builder, y necesito filtrar una fecha por año y mes.

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p')
    ->where('p.almacen = :almacen')
    ->andWhere('p.estado != :cerrado')
    ->andWhere('p.estado != :cancelado')
    ->orderBy('p.id', 'ASC')
    ->setParameter('almacen', $almacen)
    ->setParameter('cerrado', 4)
    ->setParameter('cancelado', 5);

return $query->getQuery()->execute();
```

Pero el Query builder no reconoce un WHERE del estilo: `YEAR(fecha) = x` lo mismo para `MONTH` y `DAY`

> He encontrado esta respuesta en stackOverflow pero me gustaría una
>   respuesta que no requiera modificar archivos de configuración.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826836/how-can-i-use-sqls-year-month-and-day-in-doctrine2

Comment: Como yo necesito filtrar que solo me muestre resultados del último mes, mi solución ha sido la siguiente: Declarar una variable decha `$fechadesde = date('Y-m-01');` y en el QueryBuilder añadir `->andWhere('p.fecha > :fecha');`, `->setParameter('fecha' , $fechadesde);` Pero si alguien sabe otra manera de hacer directamente lo que pregunto se agradece para que esa pregunta quede respondida.

Comment: Hace tiempo he intentado lo mismo, a menos que uses un like en la consulta de la fecha, debes modificar la configuración de doctrine para que te permita usar las funciones YEAR y MONTH